# Count of elements from the array

Tags: java

I am counting the element from array, which is greater then the given element (k)

```
   // Java implementation of the approach
class GFG
{
     
// Function to return the count of elements
// from the array which are greater than k
static int countGreater(int arr[], int n, int k) //arr-array, n-array length, k-number
{
//here first I sorted array
    int l = 0;
    int r = n - 1;
 
    // Stores the index of the left most element
    // from the array which is greater than k
    int leftGreater = n;
 
    // Finds number of elements greater than k
    while (l <= r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
 
        // If mid element is greater than
        // k update leftGreater and r
        if (arr[m] > k) {
            leftGreater = m;
            r = m - 1;
        }
 
        // If mid element is less than
        // or equal to k update l
        else
            l = m + 1;
    }
 
    // Return the count of elements greater than k
    return (n - leftGreater);
}
```

I solved with comparing only one number, but what if I have an array to compare with

Comment: Sort `arr2` and use the previous `leftGreaterThan` as the starting `left` value of your binary search for each `k` in `arr2`?

Comment: How can I use leftGreaterThan if its alreat leftGreater?

Comment: Why not loop through the array and just count the elements that are greater than k? That way you don't have to sort the array. Sometimes the answer doesn't have to be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `O(nk)` solution would be to go through `arr` for each number in `arr2` and count the number of values that are greater.

```
static int[] countGreater(Integer arr[], int n, Integer arr2[], int k)
{       
    int[] res = new int[arr2.length];
    
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int v : arr)
            if(v > arr2[i]) count++;
        res[i] = count;
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

However, we can do better than this by extending the method you've already identified - sorting `arr` and using binary search to identify the position of each value in `arr2`. If `arr2` is also sorted then we can use the previously identified position as the initial left-hand edge of our binary search, since we know that subsequent elements in `arr2` have to be greater than the current value.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static int[] countGreater(Integer arr[], int n, Integer arr2[], int k)
{
    Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(arr));
    // assume arr2 is sorted, otherwise results could be out of order
    
    int[] res = new int[arr2.length];
    
    for(int i=0, pos=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        pos = 1 + Arrays.binarySearch(arr, pos, n, arr2[i]);
        if(pos < 0) pos = -pos;
        res[i] = n - pos;
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

I've simplified the code quite a bit by making use of the `Arrays.binarySearch` method.

For small values of `n` and `k` the simple approach will probably be faster, but as they grow the binarySearch approach will take over, despite the cost of the initial sort.

Answer (score 1):

There is a varying solutions. So, I can show you several.

First of all, you don't need properties that store the length of an array. You have to do that in C/C++, but not in Java.

Here are some **solutions**:

1. A simple solution

```java
private static int[] countGreater(int[] arr, int[] arr2) {
    int walkThroughArrayLength = arr2.length;
    int[] result = new int[walkThroughArrayLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < walkThroughArrayLength; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int a1 : arr) {
            if (a1 > arr2[i]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        result[i] = counter;
    }
    return result;
}
```

2. Solution with Stream API

```java
private static int[] countGreater(int[] arr, int[] arr2) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr2)
            .map(a2 ->
                    (int) Arrays.stream(arr)
                            .filter(a1 -> a1 > a2)
                            .count())
            .toArray();
}
```

Comment: but I need to realize that method and return int[]

Comment: New answer is here. Check this out!

P.S. Sorry for waiting

Answer (score 0):

This is easier when stream is used. You can simply do

```
public static long countGreater(int[] arr, int k) {

    IntStream stream = IntStream.of(arr);

    long count = stream.filter(number -> number > k).count();

    return count;
}
```